# Why are the heights of the divs in my flex items so tiny?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue where the height of the divs in my flex items are really small, as shown in the image below. (The really hard to see red line across the second and third flex items.) I have attached the HTML, CSS and a jsfiddle. If I were to use a fixed value for the divs instead, it would work fine. Any help greatly appreciated!

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/a9bnodu3/3/

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.flexbox-container {
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
}
.flexbox-container-one {
    justify-content: center;
}
.flexbox-container-two {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flexbox-item {
    width: 37.5%;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    background-color: #777;
}
.flexbox-item-edge {
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
.flexbox-item-nav {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 4;
}
.flexbox-item-snub {
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 100%;
    flex-grow: 4;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    flex: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
}
.grid-item {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class='flexbox-container flex-container-one'>
        <div class='flexbox-item flexbox-item-edge'>

        </div>
        <div class='flexbox-item flexbox-item-nav'>
            <div class='grid-container'>
                <div class='grid-item'>

                </div>
                <div class='grid-item'>
                    
                </div>
                <div class='grid-item'>
                    
                </div>
                <div class='grid-item'>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flexbox-item flexbox-item-snub'>
            <div class='flex-container flex-container-two'>
                <div class='grid-item'>

                </div>
                <div class='grid-item'>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='flexbox-item flexbox-item-edge'>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: height:100% to .grid-container

Comment: Try using the grid instead of flex, it's easier and better in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this adding this to your css:

```
.grid-container {
    height: 100%;
}
```